# WPF TabControl remove header padding?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0, tabcontrol

I am trying to make it so that I can perform a command when the user clicks on a TabItem header in my TabControl.

Here is my code:

```
      <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" BorderThickness="1,0,0,0">
        <TabItem Selector.IsSelected="{Binding IsGeneric, Mode=OneWay}">
            <TabItem.Header>
                <Button Content="Generic" Margin="0" Command="{Binding GenericSelected}"></Button>
            </TabItem.Header>
            <V:WasteEstimationGenericView DataContext="{Binding}"></V:WasteEstimationGenericView>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Selector.IsSelected="{Binding IsSTP, Mode=OneWay}">
            <TabItem.Header>
                <Button Content="STP" Margin="0" Command="{Binding STPSelected}"></Button>
            </TabItem.Header>
            <V:WasteEstimationSTPView DataContext="{Binding STPViewModel}"></V:WasteEstimationSTPView>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

However I end up this something that looks like this:
[image: TabControl Headers]

Can someone please tell me how to make my TabControl headers consume all the available space in the TabItem Header? I originally wanted to do this using a label but it had a problem where if the user clicked towards the edge of the header it would not execute the command, I would still prefer this to using buttons, but the buttons allow the users to target where they click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to Modify the [`TabItem` ControlTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754137.aspx), more specifically the `ContentPresenter`, setting the `VerticalAlignment` and `HorizontalAlignment` to Stretch and setting the `Margin` to what you are wanting, it is defaulted to 12,2,12,2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" BorderThickness="1,0,0,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
```

Comment: I created a test project based on your code minus the view bindings and the STP button width stretched to meet the Generic button width. Are you able to create a new window and just test with only the TabControl? I suspect a parent container of the TabControl is causing your problem.

Comment: It would take a lot of work to isolate just that control, but I am not after buttons of the same length, I am looking for them to fill the available space etc. Also setting the horizontal content alignment on the tab control did not seem to alter button dimensions.